# Vue + Astro: Is it posible for astro pages to get data from scoped slots of vue component?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, astrojs

Vue allows child components to pass data to parent components using scoped slots this way:

```
//child.vue

<template>
  <slot :msg="'pass me up!'">default message</slot>
</template>

//parent.vue

<template>
  <Child v-slot="{ msg }">{{ msg }}</Child>
</template>
```

And astro has its own version which is:

```
---
//Child.astro
const html = await Astro.slots.render('default', [Astro.props.msg.toUpperCase()]);
---
<Fragment set:html={html} />

---
//Parent.astro
---
<Child>{ msg => <span>{msg}</span> }</Child>
```

Is there a way to make Astro access vue scoped slots? Like the following? (which does not work btw)

```
//child.vue

<template>
  <slot :msg="'message from vue!'"></slot>
</template>

---
//Parent.astro
---
<Child>
  { t => <span>{t}</span> }
</Child>
```

*Please ignore the fact that the imports and other boilerplate is ignored for these examples*

**UPDATE**

i found a workaround (but naturally, it's not ideal)

```
//child.vue

<template>
  <template v-if="renderer">
    <span v-slot="renderer('message from vue!')"></span>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <slot v-else :msg="'message from vue!'"></slot>
  </template>
</template>

---
//Parent.astro
---
<Child renderer={ (t : string) => `<span>${t}</span>` }></Child>
```

*i wrote this here and not as an answer because i believe there should be a better proper answer, better than mine*

Comment: Including an answer (even one that is not sufficient, by your own standards) into the question is not recommended. It adversely affects the question's indexing and its ability to attract user who might need an answer to this question. In short, it goes agains [SO] principles and recommendations. Add it as a proper answer, specify you hope for a better one and, should the better answer materialise, you can always delete yours and accept the other one. A workaround answer is better than no answer and you might discover there's no better alternative.

Comment: i guess you're right so ok :'0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i could not find any other answer, this is my best try:

```js
//child.vue

<template>
  <template v-if="renderer">
    <span v-html="renderer('message from vue!')"></span>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <slot v-else :msg="'message from vue!'"></slot>
  </template>
</template>
```

```
---
//Parent.astro
---
<Child renderer={ (t : string) => `<span>${t}</span>` }/>
```